# Modularize 'rollup.config' | "Error: Could not resolve 'path/to/module' from rollup.config.js"

Tags: javascript, bundle, rollup, rollupjs, modularity

I'm in the process of implementing `rollup` into my mono repo library for better bundling.

#### Issue

Since the library is a mono repo, I want to reuse build configurations for the individual packages. I've tried to do so by outsourcing methods that return specific `build configurations`(e.g. `createCommonJsConfig()`, `createESMConfig()`) into a file called `rollup.default.config.ts` which is located at the root of the mono repo.

These functions are then imported into the `rollup.config.js` file of each package to create the final `rollup configuration`.

```js
// rollup.config.js of an individual package

import {
  createCommonJSConfig,
  createDeclarationConfig,
  createESMConfig,
} from '../rollup.config.default';

// https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#configuration-files
export default function () {
  return [
    createDeclarationConfig(),
    createCommonJSConfig(),
    createESMConfig({ multiFileOutput: true }),
  ];
}
```

Unfortunately, as soon as I import the `rollup.config.default.ts` file into a `rollup.config.js` file of a package, I get this error:

```
[!] Error: Could not resolve '../rollup.config.default' from rollup.config.js
```

#### Question

Does anybody know whether it is possible to somehow modularize a `rollup.config.js` file to reuse commonly used parts.

- repo: https://github.com/agile-ts/agile
- `rollup.default.config.ts`: https://github.com/agile-ts/agile/blob/removing-internal/packages/rollup.config.default.ts

Thanks a lot ;D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this issue by being consistent with my `config` file `extension`
-> After I've transformed the `rollup.default.config.ts` file to a `rollup.default.config.js` file it worked as expected.